# .htaccess Redirect all html files to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have strange problem with `.htaccess` file.
The file is placed inside directory `www.mydomain.com/t/` and looks like that:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+).html$ ../index.php [R=301]
```

I would like to redirect all .html files to my main page www.mydomain.com

Redirection works but I am redirected to `www.mydomain.com/server/file/path/t/index.php` not to `www.mydomain.com` (or `www.mydomain.com/index.php`)

Where did I make a mistake?

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Almost :) `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [R=301]` works as I need. Thanks!